# Inline function of my code is not storing string the string value

Tags: c++, oop, inline-functions

I am following an online tutorial which is quite similar to my code, but not exactly the same. I have modified it so that I can have a better understanding of it, but I am having problems getting/returning the string value from the inline function. The string value becomes empty as soon as the compiler exits the last curly bracket of `Another.cpp`.

Is there any way to solve my issue without changing the structure of my files as well as the code? Particularly, **I don't want to change anything from the `Another.h`**. Please, if someone can explain what could be the reason behind the inline function here as well, will really appreciate that.

**Another.h**

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include"Temple.h"
#include<memory>

namespace NamespaceAn
{
    class Test
    {
    public:
        static void Init();
        inline static std::shared_ptr<Outside::Inside>& GetString() { return s_String; }
    private:
        static std::shared_ptr<Outside::Inside> s_String;

    };
}
```

**Another.cpp**

```
#include "Another.h"
#include<string>

namespace NamespaceAn 
{
    std::shared_ptr<Outside::Inside>Test::s_String;

    void Test::Init()
    {
        //This s_String value is getting disapprear as soon as the compiler get out of the curly bracket

        auto s_String = Outside::Inside("asdf");

        //below all are commented out for the Another.cpp
        //std::string  Ast = "asdf";

        /*std::string Ast = "asdf";
        auto s_String = new Outside::Inside(Ast);*/

        /*Outside::Inside* ob = new Outside::Inside(Ast);
        auto s_String = &(ob->Get());*/
        //                               *****    Attention ****
        //no operator "=" matches the operands and binary '=' no operator found which takes a right-hand ooperand of type std::string*(no acceptable conversion)
        //s_String = &(ob->Get());



        //auto s_String = Ast;

        //auto s_String = Outside::Inside("asdf");
        
        //auto s_String = new Outside::Inside("asdf");

        //s_String = reinterpret_cast<Ast>;
        //*s_String = &(Outside::Inside("asdf"));
        //s_String = reinterpret_cast<Outside::Inside*>(&Outside::Inside("asdf"));

    }
}
```

**Temple.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace Outside
{
    class Inside
    {
        std::string m_String = "tesi";
    public:
        Inside(std::string x) 
        {
            m_String = x;
        }
        std::string Get() 
        {
            return m_String;
        }

        /*std::string* m_String;
    public:
        Inside(std::string &x)
        {
            m_String = &x;
        }
        std::string Get()
        {
            return 
            *m_String;
        }*/


        /*template<typename T>
        static T Set(T x) 
        {
            return T;
        }*/
    };

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include"Another.h"
#include<memory>



int main() 
{
    NamespaceAn::Test::Init();

        /*auto asdf = NamespaceAn::Test::GetString();
        std::cout << asdf << std::endl;*/

        std::cout << NamespaceAn::Test::GetString();
    
    std::cin.get();
}
```

**Extra**

Inside of `Another.cpp`, I have also tried the following code:

```
std::string  Ast = "asdf";
Outside::Inside* ob = new Outside::Inside(Ast);
auto s_String = &(ob->Get());
```

Comment: `#pragma once` in your `main.cpp` is very odd.

Comment: i have removed it and I forgot tot add that i was getting 00000000 as the answer, as the s_String value is getting empty as soon as the compiler exit the last curly bracket of Another.cpp

Comment: I think provided too much code especially since much of it is commented out.

Comment: `inline static std::shared_ptr<Outside::Inside>& GetString(...` is odd, in my opinion.  Should either return `std::shared_ptr<Outside::Inside>` or `Outside::Inside const&` or `Outside::Inside` or `std::string`.

Comment: @Apachi "_i have removed it_" - No, it's still there.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am having some issues with my xombrero browser will fix ASAP.

Comment: This is breaking my brain. Can you simplify it please

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings i can understand your frustration, as I myself is not an native English speaker.

Answer (score 3):

In `Test::Init`, this line:

```
auto s_String = Outside::Inside("asdf");
```

declares a local variable `s_String` that shadows the static member variable. So when you exit the function, you are seeing the original value of the static member variable, which was never modified.

Instead, simply do:

```
s_String = Outside::Inside("asdf");
```

to assign to the static member variable. Since `s_String` is a `shared_ptr`, what you're looking for is probably:

```
s_String = std::make_shared(Outside::Inside("asdf"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried it, and it doesn't work., I can't even  use s_String without the auto either.

Comment: What happens when you try that? Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: I forgot tot add that i was getting 00000000 as the answer, as the s_String value is getting empty as soon as the compiler exit the last curly bracket of Another.cpp also when i used this 
 //no operator "=" matches the operands and binary '=' no operator found which 
takes a right-hand ooperand of type std::string*(no acceptable conversion)
      
  //s_String = &(ob->Get());

Comment: Another.cpp probably should have: `s_String = std::make_shared<Outside::Inside>("asdf");`

Comment: before getting outside of the curly bracket from Another.cpp the compiler is showing that auto s_String is storing the correct value but after the curly bracket it becomes empty.

Comment: @Apachi You have declared a local variable. When you exit the function, you are looking at the member variable, but that was never modified.

Comment: s_String = std::make_shared<Outside::Inside>("asdf"); thanks this is returning the register address and not the string value, now what can i do to get the string value from it

Comment: You can use `.get()`, and `*` as needed. See the [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: My brain is getting overflowed by looking at all of the reference, I guess i have learn how to read all the reference too, by the way i am a beginner and. currently i don't know how to optimally use reference but i will try, I have one more question please can you explain what is the purpose behind inline Getstring () here, i have read somewhere that by using inline we don't declare function again and again or something similar. Sorry i am just blabbing here. I am beginner hope you ll understand.